# Tree decomposition of graphs with low height

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Fix a parameter D and let the $D$-treewidth be the minimum width among tree-decompositions of H where the underlying tree has height D.

We know:

- 1-tw $= |V(H)|$.
- 2-tw $\leq vc(H)$, but this is not tight, as the matching has small 2-tw. Here $vc(H)$ is vertex cover number.
- b-tw $\leq 4 \cdot tw(H) + 3$ for $b \geq O(log |V(H)|)$, by this paper: https://research-explorer.ista.ac.at/download/5427/5471/IST-2014-314-v1%2B1_long.pdf

Can we say something in general about D-treewidth? In particular, how does $D$-treewidth decrease as we increase $D$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to address this question is to think of a tree decomposition as an unrooted tree. Then, it is easy to see that its diameter is related to the depth by a factor of 2. Searching for diameter, instead of depth, may help you find more related results.

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0055821) by Bodlaender and Hagerup, for example, they do something which sounds like the inverse function of what you want: they determine some pretty good bounds on the minimum diameter necessary in a decomposition of a graph of treewidth $k$, if you allow bags to have width $K > k$.